# Extracting data from nested JSON with escape backslash characters by using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a non-standard format of JSON which is using some nested data with backslash escape characters.

```
{
"getFeedFromMyTeam": [
    {
        "OpenedAt": 1693321311,
        "feedData": "{\"keyOne\":\"my_data_one\",\"keyTwo\":\"my_data_two\"}",
        "feedId": "123456789",
        "recipients": [
            {
                "receiverId": "johns",
                "receiverName": "John Smith"
            }
        ],
        "senderId": "janed",
        "senderName": "Jane Doe"
    }

],
"hasMore": true,
"paginationToken": "100"  
}
```

I'm trying to convert it to a CSV file with this comand:

```
cat my.json | jq -r '.getFeedFromMyTeam[] | .recipients[] as $t | [.OpenedAt,$t.receiverId,$t.receiverName,.senderId,.feedData] | @csv'
```

All is good however instead of full ".feedData" which now looks like:

```
"{""keyOne"":""my_data_one"",""keyTwo"":""my_data_two""}"
```

I would like to get only data from "keyTwo" which is "my_data_two"

Now it is:

```
1693321311,"johns","John Smith","janed","{""keyOne"":""my_data_one"",""keyTwo"":""my_data_two""}"
```

I would like to get:

```
1693321311,"johns","John Smith","janed","my_data_two"
```

Ideally I would like to use only jq but if not possible then maybe also awk, sed etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`feedData` is a JSON object, so you can convert it with `fromjson`:

```bash
$ jq -r '.getFeedFromMyTeam[] | .recipients[] as $t | [.OpenedAt,$t.receiverId,$t.receiverName,.senderId,(.feedData | fromjson | .keyTwo)] | @csv' file.json
1693321311,"johns","John Smith","janed","my_data_two"
```

Answer (score 1):

[`fromjson`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#convert-to-from-json) allows you to parse a JSON-string into the corresponding JSON entity.

e.g.:

```
$ jq 'fromjson' <<EOF
"{\"a\":1}"
EOF
{
  "a": 1
}
```

Integrating into your filter:

```
jq <my.json -r '.getFeedFromMyTeam[] | .recipients[] as $t
| [.OpenedAt,$t.receiverId,$t.receiverName,.senderId,(.feedData|fromjson.keyTwo)]
| @csv'
```